# Zend Soap Server / WSDL

Tags: php, xml, zend-framework, soap, wsdl

I've been working on a project (which I'll keep specific details out of this post with randomized data) that involves integrating our system (PHP 5.3.x+) with an API (they provided a SDK) of a major company. They provided a WSDL and claimed ours needed to match their methods and they provided examples of how output (XML generated by the Soap Server) should look.

Right now, everything has been working as expected. When I send a XML request from SoapUI (an app I'm using to test) it all processes properly and such, but the XML output isn't matching closely with their examples and we believe they said we must be close to their examples.

Basically, we created an agnostic class we initialize with a service name and it initializes into a non-agnostic class which is used via the following:

```
/**
 * The following is used to process Soap Server based on config and any optional settings.
 *
 * @param string $className
 * @param array $options
 * @param object $config
 * @return Zend_Soap_Server
 */
public static function init($className, Array $options = null, $config = null)
{
    // Used to define the class and return object.
    $soap_server        = new Zend_Soap_Server(null, $options);
    $soap_server->setClass($className, null, (isset($config) ? $config : null));
    $soap_server->handle();
    exit;
}
```

The problem itself lies within the outputted response. How would you guys suggest we build the XML output if they're very specific about everything?

1.) One of our methods is moneyTransferRequest. When I send the XML over for this, it does find the method and processes it. However, they want it to show the method name, in the response, as moneyTransferResponse but it outputs moneyTransferRequestResponse.

2.) Our output (for variables and such sent back as an object) has multiple variables, we'll say $money for example. The field for this would return as:

```
<money xsi:type="xsd:string">10.0</money>
```

They would like it to be:

```
<ns1:money xsi:type="xsd:string">10.0</money>
```

in the return.

I appreciate any help and input on the subject.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key feature of SOAP is that it uses XML, and XML can come in a bunch of different styles but still mean the same.

I think (but I can only guess because you didn't provide details) that your two issues might be non-existing.

1.) The name of the response XML structure should align with the name mentioned in the WSDL. YOU are publishing the WSDL, so you should check if these two match. Note that the important entry point is the SOAP method - everything thereafter is defined in the WSDL itself, any consuming client should be able to figure it out as long as the names mentioned are correctly used.

2.) This is basically the same, but even easier: XML allows to use namespaces, and these can be defined in several locations, with the result being not literally the same, but every XML parser will understand that they are the same. So you should check whether the namespace that is required as "ns1" is mentioned in the XML header of your response. Every XML document has a base namespace, which does not need to be repeated on every element that belongs to it.

This is the case with the `<money>` element. Your style of writing uses that base namespace, their style of writing uses a namespace shortcut `ns1` also introduced in the XML header, but not declared as the base namespace. So as long as there are traces of the correct XML namespace in both responses, I'd assume they are equivalent.

And the bad news would be that you cannot change how the PHP SoapServer generates the XML. You'd need to create your own implementation of a SOAP server, which I'd say is a complete waste of resources.

Comment: Hi there, thanks a lot for your response. I finally read it. We kind of figured there wasn't much we could do besides formulate a response ourselves that matched their non-standard guidelines. Anyway, this was very helpful and clarified a few things for me.